# ArrayField of ImageField in Django 1.8

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to use an [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) to store multiple images on a Django model.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    pictures = ArrayField(models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="<some_url>"), size=5)
```

However the admin page does not show the expected interface (like a "Choose file" button):

[image]

How can I, for instance, have a set of `n` "Choose file" buttons displayed to perform the image upload?

Comment: It is not supported: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25756 . You can create a separate `Attachment`model and link to your `MyModel` through a FK relation.

Comment: Oh that's a shame. I think I'm better off having 4 or 5 additional `ImageField`s rather than an wrapper model for `ImageField`. I don't want to introduce unnecessary table JOINs and I don't need that many images for my model anyway.

Comment: You can try using the `MultiFileField` supplied by user `riccardodivirgilio` in the ticket I linked to, but obviously there is no guarantee that it will keep working in future Django versions.